# Extract URL query parameters with AngularUI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, query-string

I am using AngularUI library and want to extract the query parameters with from a URL 
(sample URL: `#\books\:categoryID?publisher=xyz` (`#\books\value?publisher=xyz`)).

The `$stateParams` extracts the data as `{categoryId:value?publisher=xyz}` but I need to get it as `{categoryId:"value", publisher:"xyz"}`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular `ui-router` has direct support for passing parameters as a query string params. There is a doc

- URL Parameters - [Query Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters)

There is a link to [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qc9yvz?p=preview), using this state definition:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('books', {
      url : '/books/:categoryID?publisher',
      template: '<div> This is a state def: '+
      '<pre>{{toNiceJson(state)}}</pre>' +
      ' These are params sent to this state:' +
      '<pre>{{toNiceJson(params)}}</pre>'+ 
      ' </div>',
      controller: 'urlParamsCtrl', 
    })
```

And these could be links to get to that state

```
<a href="#/books/value?publisher=xyz">...
<a href="#/books/other?publisher=unknown%20publisher">...
<a ui-sref="books({categoryID:'value', publisher:'xyz'})">...
<a ui-sref="books({categoryID:'other', publisher:'unknown publisher'})">...
```

See more [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qc9yvz?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks!!! that worked.
I had an old code snippet that was using $location for setting a new url and ui-router was not able to get the query parameters.
After seeing your example I realized I should be using the state.go('myState', {state parameters}) and got it working. Thanks

Comment: Exactly! I would say that ui-router is most likely the best choice you can do ;)

Answer (score 0):

inject $routeParams and use:

```
$routeParams.categoryID
```

to get the value.

Comment: that returns {categoryId:value?publisher=xyz}
ngRoute doesn't have enough support for query params and maintaining nested views that's when I switched to angular-ui.